# what's the best package to add to an Ubuntu VPS account to get a terminal window?

Tags: command-line, server, gui, ssl, https

For my Pair Networks VPS (running Ubuntu 10.04 on AMD64), and working install details with its illustrious support team, I am interested in suggestions for a robust terminal quasi-GUI'd window package for using grep, egrep, ed, sed, find, I/O piping, and redirection of stdin/stdout/stderr), i.e., accessible through my SSL-secured (https) URL? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Before you consider anything else, ask yourself "What's wrong with SSH?" a hundred times. It's secure, supports better authentication (omgwhy are you still using passwords?!) and doesn't result in a server-side language running in a capacity that can su up to a privileged account.

That said, there are [a number of options](https://superuser.com/questions/309392/linux-console-session-over-http) for providing web-access to a terminal console. [`shellinabox`](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/) or [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) seem to be the most viable options.

I wouldn't trust *any* of them. Just use a SSH client.